# Is there a hibernate dialect class for ANSI SQL 2016?

Tags: sql, hibernate, ansi-sql

my customer uses an oracle19 database as a managed service. The service provider requires that the SQLs running against his database must be compatible with ANSI SQL 2016. In hibernate package I didn't unfortunately found any dialect class, which meet this requirement.

Did someone have a similar problem and could give me a pointer?

Thank You very much!

Comment: Strange request given the fact that Oracle doesn't even fully support ANSI SQL 2016

Comment: Yes, You are right. The reqirenment means actually that oracle's extentions to ANSI SQL schould not be used. The only partial support of ANSI 2016 by the database itself ist not an issue for us.

Comment: I'm not sure any database supports the full ANSI 2016 standard. It typically should support the mandatory components, which Oracle does. I think the issue being described here is that the database shouldn't use features outside of what is being described in the 2016 standard. Which is hard but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such dialect. You will have to use the Oracle dialect e.g. `Oracle12cDialect`.